# How to display an image in a GridView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to show the database from SQL Server to a GridView using C# and wanted to show the image within the control. I am using the code below to show the database.

```
protected void txtsinglesearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "First Name")
    {  
        string q = "select * from facultyreg where fname like'" + txtsinglesearch.Text.ToString() + "%' ";
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(q, con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds, "facultyreg");
        grdvw_sigsrch_by_name.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        grdvw_sigsrch_by_name.DataBind();
    }
}
```

This code is inside the TextChanged event of TextBox where I am searching the initial letter from the database and display the result in the GridView

Comment: what datatype you use for image column for table in database??

Comment: http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2013/11/how-to-display-images-in-gridview-from.html#.U2DQB1fkWGo use this link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [TemplateFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx)

e.g.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Img" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("yourImagepath")%>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Or there is an example of [Displaying Images in a GridView Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx)